# Nuxt3; Files uploaded and stored in public folder cannot be found even though other ones can

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am using nuxt 3 to create a web app where users can upload files. For now, I store them in the public folder where I assumed they would get served to users

Other files like favicon get served but not the uploaded files, I get a 404 error, during `yarn dev` it seems to work fine but not after building with `yarn build`. [this is screenshot of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdLut.png) the favicon.ico, can be accessed but not the newly uploaded screenshot. How can I mitigate this?

Full project - https://github.com/kgarchie/Ticketer

I tried searching online, but I can't seem to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resorted to building an api endpoint to serve the files, instead of trying to make nuxt serve them. It seems the files in the public directory are static and not expected to change.